# Display and hide a div onclick

Tags: javascript, html, css

This is a demo of a sidebar, when i click on login it should display the login form, and when i click again it should hide it. 
I don't know how to do that. Any hints?
I have also another problem, the bar hide part of the content how to solve that?
Thank you very much for any help.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Iuppiter/uDxH6/61/

```
// Clicking here will show/hide the div
<a href="#">Login</a>
<div id="login-form"> ... </div>
```

Without using Jquery maybe.

Comment: If u use jQuery have a look at the `.toggle()` function

Comment: Simply use toggleClass - http://jsfiddle.net/uDxH6/63/

Comment: @SeanDoe Why would you do that? If you just want to make it visible (no animation) just use `.toggle()`.

Comment: it is possible not to use jquery only js?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With only the code your provided you can do this.

http://jsfiddle.net/uDxH6/62/

```
$("#login-form").hide();
$("#other-bar-top a:nth-child(4)").click(function(e) {
    $("#login-form").slideToggle();
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Make sure to include jQuery on your website.

Comment: it is possible not to use jquery only js?

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this,

HTML:

```
<a href="#" id="login">Login</a>
```

Jquery:

```
 $(function(){
       $("#login-form").hide();
       $("#login").click(function(){
            $("#login-form").toggle();
      });
 });
```

Comment: it is possible not to use jquery only js?